# How configure in a master machine Maven to let reuse its repository content just how reference for a LAN? (No copy of jars)

Tags: java, maven

I have a LAN, where each developer machine has **Maven** installed and of course each one has its own repository defined through the `settings.xml` file through the `<localRepository>` section, for example:

- `\username\maven\repository` (custom)

It how a generic way, it without matter if the OS is either Linux, Mac, or Windows

The goal is to have just one machine in the LAN to let access to its own repository for the other machines in the same LAN, it of course to let them *refer* the dependencies as they need or request through their projects. Therefore as follows:

```
* Developer Master [central repository in the LAN]
* Developer Alpha
* Developer Beta
* Developer Delta
```

Therefore Alpha, Beta, Delta are dependent developer machines - since now referred to as *DDM*. This DDM should get access to the dependencies available by Master.

**Requirement**: an important consideration is that the DDMs must do not download or make a copy of those jars dependencies from the master to themselves - just refer them; therefore the purpose is to save space about hard disk in this DDM. And if in some project from these DDM is declared a new dependency through a pom.xml file should be downloaded into the master and be accessible to all the rest DDM too.

**Question:** in each DDM - *of course if is possible*

- How configure each Maven's `settings.xml` file to refer the *remote repository*?

*Therefore*, it with the purpose to avoid to configure each `pom.xml` file for each project in the DDM. It would be verbose.

**Goal**: having in the Master Machine the Maven repository directory with dependencies about Spring, JUnit 5, Hibernate, and others, they should be available for all the DDM through Maven. Therefore is better to avoid have each DDM with 3GB in their repositories and *practically with the same data*, for this scenario the purpose is to save disk space in the DDMs. So is needed to have in only in the master the 3GB in its repository. *BTW 3GB could be really 5 to 10 - just in case.*

BTW if you think to suggest about Artifactory, seems is not possible:

- [How configure in a master machine Artifactory to reuse the repository location defined in Maven's settings.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845671/how-configure-in-a-master-machine-artifactory-to-reuse-the-repository-location-d)

Not sure if Nexus can accomplish this goal.

But I want to know how to accomplish this goal with Maven.

Other suggestion or approach to avoid repeat the same data through the DDMs and save space is welcome

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that in standard Maven. People usually don't care because what are 10GB if you have 1TB hard disk? The only place where I care is on the build server (which at the moment has 1800 separate local repositories for each Java project we have), and I haven't found a good solution yet. Maybe you can have a look at https://github.com/takari/takari-local-repository but I don't know if this is a fit for you.

Comment: @JFMeier thanks for the link ... I will do a research. Even with a 1TB of HD - consider a team with laptops working with VirtualBox and running out of space - ... the point is have a central point and avoid repeat the same data - about the repositories. BTW - Does this situation happen for Gradle too? It is my next technology to research about this request.